# How does one access $PWD variable on windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

The variable to access the current directory under linux is is $PWD. How does one access the variable corresponding to $PWD in windows?

This is for users with a unix background. So looking at info about mklink, a windows link utility, I found that the syntax of mklink is

```
mklink "c:\where\link\is\to\be\created\file.txt"  "c:\where\file\actually\exists\file.txt"
```

But I want to replace this with

```
mklink $PWD "c:\where\file\actually\exists\file.txt"
```

But using $PWD throws error. I come from the linux world where `$PWD` referred to the current working directory.

What would be the correct syntax so that the link is created in `$PWD` whenever the script is executed?

Comment: OK I found the answer myself and it seemed to work:

Comment: Was it just using %cd%? Be sure to post your solution and mark it as correct for future generations.

Comment: yes using '%cd% as a substiture for $PWD worked

Comment: Please don't tag a question with a piece of technology you don't even plan using, PowerShell in this case.

Comment: Do not edit answers into questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK I found the answer myself and it seemed to work: mklink "%cd%\file.txt" "c:\where\file\actually\exists\file.txt"

Answer (score 0):

mklink is a subcommand of CMD.EXE. It must be run "inside" of CMD.EXE. From Powershell you can say:

```
cmd /c mklink  # without args mklink gives you help
```

Online help is here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194(v=ws.10).aspx. You have a choice of file softlinks, directory softlinks, hardlinks, and directory junctions.

Sometimes it can be tricky invoking a CMD subcommand from Powershell because of the need for escape characters. In PSv3 this situation is improved with the magic -% See this blog for details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/06/14/new-v3-language-features.aspx. Search for "Easier Reuse of Command Lines From Cmd.exe"

Comment: I created a regular text file.bat without using cmd and executed it on the command prompt. did not use powershell. did not use cmd /c either.

Comment: I think the post was tagged with "Powershell". I assumed you were using powershell. Maybe this will help someone else who does want to invoke CMD subcommands from PS, which can be tricky. I was surprised when I found out that the caret (^) is CMD's escape character.